# Python not creating new module

Tags: python

I am following the tutorial: https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-whatsapp-message-30-seconds-python. The very first line is the very first error.

```
python3 -m pywhatsapp
```

I get the error of invalid syntax on the 'p'. How do I get my python installation to accept this code? No pip commands work either.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comment in the same blog saying that the command to run is actually

```
python3 -m venv pywhatsapp
```

This command must not be typed in the python shell. It must be typed in an ordinary terminal.

Comment: If the Python installation is on Windows, it's usually just `python` (rather than `python3`).

Comment: @Anaksunaman If this happens on Windows, the command to activate the virtualenv probably doesn't use the 'source' command as the blog indicates.